# Find name of computer attached to same network

Tags: networking, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, hostname

I have two PCs connected to the same network. One is mine and there is one other. I want to find out the Name of the other PC using the command line. Please note:

- There are only two PC's connected to the network
- IPv4 IP address of my PC is 192.168.0.2
- IPv4 IP address of the other PC is 192.168.0.1
- They both have Windows 7, 32-Bit
- I don't just have to find the name, I have to store it in a variable for later use in my batch script.

**Note:** Don't give me any code as Stack Exchange is not a free code writing service. But please at least give me the outline of the required steps.

Comment: See my answer on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785413/use-powershell-to-get-device-names-and-their-ipaddress-on-a-home-network)

Comment: `dig -x 192.168.0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to translate an IP address to a name will depend on what name resolution services (e.g. DNS) are configured on your network, so not all commands will work in all cases. Assuming default network configurations, here are a few commands you can try listed in (roughly) the order they're likely to work:

#### Nbtstat

```
nbtstat -A <IP-ADDRESS>
```

Queries the remote machine's NetBIOS name table. The name with type "UNIQUE" is the remote machine's name:

```
PS C:\> nbtstat -A 192.0.2.100

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [192.0.2.100] Scope Id: []

           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    WIN10-PC       <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered
    WIN10-PC       <20>  UNIQUE      Registered

    MAC Address = 0B-15-5A-AB-0C-15
```

#### Ping

```
ping -a <IP-ADDRESS>
```

The `-a` parameter resolves an IP address to a hostname. This requires working DNS on the network that knows about the destination machine.

```
PS C:\> ping -a 192.0.2.100

Pinging WIN10-PC [192.0.2.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.0.2.100:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```